# Parallel detectCores() giving incorrect output on a Virtual machine

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I'm just doing some performance testing on a new laptop. My problem starts when I tried to test it on parallel computing.

So, when I run the function detectCores()  from parallel the result is 1. The problem is that the laptop has an i7- 4800MQ processor which as 4 cores. 
As a result when I run my code it thinks that it has only one core and the time to execute the code is exactly the same as without the parallelization.

I’ve tested the code in a different machine with an i5 processor also with 4 cores using the same R version (R 3.0.2 64 bits) and the code runs perfectly. The only difference is that the new computer as installed windows 8.1 while the old one has windows 7 
Also, when I run Sys.getenv(“NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS”) I also get 1 as an answer.

I've search the internet looking for an answer with no joy. As anyone came across this problem before?

Manny thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are loading the **parallel** package before running **detectCores()**. I also have an i-7 processor (Windows 8.1, 64 Bit) and I am able to see as 8 cores when I run **detectCores(logical = TRUE)** and I get 4 when I run **detectCores(logical = FALSE)**. For more, kindly refer this [link](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/parallel/html/detectCores.html). HTH

Comment: Vivek, you have pointed me in the right way. The help file mentions that in virtual machines the function returns the number of cores made available to that VM.  I’m running the laptop with one host and two VM. So all the ram and all processors are split among those (not my preferred choice). 
I’ve asked IT to increase the number of processors to two and it is now working. cheers

Comment: Great to hear that. I am editing your question for a larger audience and please accept if it helped. Cheers!